# Check if string exists in JSON array then what is the value of other key in SQL (jsonb column)

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

This is the data inside a jsonb column in my postgres table. I have a query where I check if this json data has a key "a" and responding value "123". Now I want to check that if this case is valid then what is the value of "b" and "c" for that item. There can be no such case where inside same jsonb row there is a duplicate of value of a. I want to get all the rows which have  {"a": "123"} and value of "b" greater than "10". Im unable to understand how i will get value of "b" so i can further compare it.I want * from table where the jsonb column has this condition. Also i have more than 1 million rows and my index is this json_col column .

```
CREATE INDEX idx_jsonb ON table
USING GIN (json_col jsonb_path_ops);



SELECT *     
FROM table 
where json_col @> '[{"a": "123"}]'
```

```json
[
  {
    "a": "123",
    "b": "456",
    "c": "789",
    "d": "888"
  },
   {
    "a": "1",
    "b": "2",
    "c": "3",
    "d": "4"
  }
]
```

Comment: So what is the result you want? Two columns with the values of `b` and `c`? What if the `{"a": "123"}` appears in more than one array element? Please **[edit]** your question and add a sample output

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It will never appear more than once in same array element.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name can you please look into it ?

Comment: So what is the result you want? Two columns with the values of `b` and `c`? Two rows with those values? A new JSON values with only those two keys? Please **[edit]** your question and add a sample output.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I want to get all the rows which have {"a": "123"} and value of "b" greater than "10".I want to get all the rows which have {"a": "123"} and value of "b" greater than "10". i have edit the question... i want * from table where the jsonb column has this condition. Also i have more than 1 million rows and my index is this jsonb column